# Internet Explorer has strange 1px difference with background-image

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

I'm using a sprite of two images and experiencing a 1px different in ALL internet explorer versions, but works fine in Firefox.

Please see demonstration here: http://jsfiddle.net/bHUs3/6/

My heart hurts. What is causing this discrepancy?

See below screen on hover in Internet explorer (no specific version)
**Edit** I'm investigating if my installation of IE isnt as sound as I thought

[image]

Comment: The only thing I notice in IE8 is some opacity funkiness but no 1px difference.

Comment: That's weird, as I see as if it were outputting 1px from the blue button area of the PNG, above when rolled over

Comment: I don't see the issue either.  Checking in IE 9 with all browser/document modes, it looks fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it is caused by the drastic change of the color of the text-shadow effect.

Notice that when the button is not hovered, the letters are somehow bolder. It seems like the white letters have a white border that is added to the current weight of the letter. It doesn't happen in the hover event because the letters have a different color.

Add +1px in the x axis and it will be smoothed.
http://jsfiddle.net/bHUs3/9/

If you want to make this change only in IE use a conditional comment:

```
<!--[if IE]>
.calltoActionReadMore {background-position:1px -24px}
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: I don't really understand your answer, as there is no text-shadow applied? Sorry - can you elaborate? :) thanks

Comment: The text in the graphic has an effect similar to a solid text-shadow. This shadow is easier to see in the hover state, on the bottom side of the characters, it seems to be a white border between the cyan characters and the semigray color of the button.

I apologize for not specifying it in my previous post. :)